# Debian squeezy dist-upgrade to wheeze (nothing up to date)

Tags: debian, upgrade

I operate 3 debian server (all server is Xen guest) with squeezy installed. Dist upgrade is needed because the old packages, 2 server is successfully upgraded but the last cannot be.
In all server i done:

`1): update all package (apt-get upgrade)`

```
2) modify the /etc/apt/sources.list to:
deb http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

# squeeze-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
```

3) apt-get update; apt-get upgrade;apt-get dist-upgrade;apt-get upgrade

The first 2 server is successfully upgraded to wheezy,
but the last wrote on upgrade: "0 package will be installed,0 package will be upgraded"
Using aptitude instead of apt-get made same result.
i checked some installed utility (man, mc, etc...) is also older in the last server,really not upgraded, and some package is unreachable which is default reachable in squeezy and wheeze
Why can't the last upgrade to wheeze?

Comment: First run "apt-get update". It should say first that if it reached or not the update server; then it should tell how many new and upgradeable packages there are. Most probably "apt-get update" failed either because you made an error in sources.list or network configuration doesn't allow access to the mirror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting but using apt with switch: -t wheezy, it can successfully upgraded.
`apt-get -t wheezy dist-upgrade`
and it's work

Answer (score 0):

You read a wrong tutorial somewhere. It contains many redundant and unnecessary steps. But to focus specifically on your question:

After you run `apt-get dist-upgrade` you are done. (If that finished successfully.) This is the part that upgraded you to wheezy.

Trying to `apt-get upgrade` again after that would result in no packages, because you are already up to date!